# Access file system in SystemJS-based Electron application

Tags: node.js, electron, aurelia, systemjs

I'm having trouble with using the "fs" module of Nodejs in my Electron app. It utilizes Aurelia and SystemJS.

When I do

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

it says

[image]

If I do

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

it gives me this error

[image]

The app is based on the Aurelia electron skeleton (ESNext)
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext

Comment: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/124

Comment: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/537

Comment: I've already gone through those two threads, but none of the suggestions there made any difference

Comment: Even [this comment](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/537#issuecomment-228348773)?

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Yes, I still get the "require is not a function" error

Comment: did you change the import to `import * as fs from 'fs!npm';`?

Comment: @JeremyDanyow yes

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to use something like this?

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var fs = remote.require('fs');
```

Comment: that gave me the same "require is not a function(...)" error